# Writing a programming command in the same line as text

Tags: code

I want to write just one Matlab-command in LaTeX. I want this command to be in the same line of my document as other text is:

some text... size(t) ...some text.

I tried \begin{verbatim} size(t) \end{verbatim}. 
But this puts the size(t) in an extra line. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `\verb+text+`? Or similar, + could be other symbol, just need to be the same at both ends

Comment: `\lstinline` with the `listings` package